# US7878151 Dog Toy - what happened to the lawsuit between Our Pet's and Kong?

Tags: infringement, lawsuit

In reference to the patent: [US7878151](https://www.google.com/patents/US7878151)

Our Pet's filed a lawsuit against Kong for this toy (patent infringement)in February 2011. Was the case ever settled?

Answer (score 2):

The lawsuit is closed, see here:

https://search.rpxcorp.com/lit/ohndce-172530-ourpet-s-company-v-kong-company

There was a joint motion to dismiss from all parties, so apparently it was settled. The documents can be accessed through PACER (thats the US courts system to access public court documents). However, it costs 0,1 dollars per page (max. $3 per document) so I'm not going to look into them. Feel free to register for PACER if you want more information, payments below the first $15 are waived (they don't have to be paid), so you could get the documents for free that way (please confirm that first, that's the last information I had, I didn't check if it's still that way).

PACER:
https://www.pacer.gov/